# Draw a Pieslice with SetPixel

Tags: slice, geometry, segment

I use an Graphical LCD together with an microcontroller.
I would like to draw some Pieslices. I only can set single Pixels.

Are there any already existing functions to draw Pieslices?
Can someone give me a hint where i can find such a function?

I would like to define start angle, stop angle and the radius.

Comment: Which programming language are you using ?

Comment: Hi Marco. I am using C. But im also happy with other Language examples, as long as they use a variant of SetPixel or use Lines with x0,y0 x1,y1